# PHP round behavior

Tags: php, floating-point, rounding

```
$r = 302 / 490;
printLn($r);
printLn(round($r, 2, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP));
```

Gives

> 0.61632653061224484947189239392173476517200469970703125
>   0.61999999999999999555910790149937383830547332763671875

Why not normal rounding to really 2 digits?

Comment: There is nothing like `printLn` in PHP

Comment: Works for me: http://codepad.viper-7.com/6HmR5G. What PHP version is this on?

Comment: PHP Version 5.3.4

System  Windows NT PAVELHP 5.1 build 2600 (Windows XP Professional Service Pack 3) i586

With print same result 

0.61632653061224484947189239392173476517200469970703125
0.61999999999999999555910790149937383830547332763671875

Comment: @deceze It's called "precision". See [edited pad](http://codepad.viper-7.com/4LktQf)

Comment: Using `print`, it just works fine in php 5.4.3. Strange results are possible in round function only if the number is negative and the precision you expect is bigger than the actual number of digits after the comma

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To within the measurable precision of floating-point numbers, the rounded number shown is `0.62`. To understand why you aren't getting exactly `0.62`, you need to understand how floating-point numbers work. Basically you can take any integer of magnitude up to 2<sup>53</sup>-1 and multiply it by any power of 2 between -1074 and 971 (inclusive). `0.62` cannot be exactly represented in this manner.

Put another way, your `precision` INI setting is too high. See [this codepad](http://codepad.viper-7.com/4LktQf). Try setting it to a more representible number, like the default 15.

Comment: You are correct. INI presision was 100, after setting it to 14 work as expected. But do you know why this property has this strange effect?

Comment: Because of the whole "number can't be represented exactly" thing. At 14 digits of precision the effect is masked by the number of significant digits, so it doesn't matter anymore, but note that internally it is still stored with that slight imprecision. If you add $r to itself 490 times, you won't get exactly 302 out.

Comment: That should be any integer of magnitude up to 2**53-1, not 2**52-1, and the exponent is any power of 2 from 2**-1074 to 2**971, not -1022 to 1023.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code using **print** instead of **printLn**, this is what I got:

```
0.61632653061224
0.62
```

Can you try to modify your code using print instead of printLn (this is a Java print)?

Comment: Note that you get significantly fewer digits too. Your `precision` configuation setting it lower than OP's.

Comment: PHP Version 5.3.4

System  Windows NT PAVELHP 5.1 build 2600 (Windows XP Professional Service Pack 3) i586

With print same result 

0.61632653061224484947189239392173476517200469970703125
0.61999999999999999555910790149937383830547332763671875